# How much cake batter to make two 6"x2" cakes?

Tags: cake, batter

I have two 6"x2" cake pans, and am wondering how many cups of a box cake mix batter I need to put into each pan?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon how thick you want it. A 6"x2" rectangular pan, filled 1" deep will obviously contain 12 cubic inches of batter. 12 cubic inches = .83 US cup. So, to fill both pans to a depth of 1 inch, you would need 1.66 cups. To fill both pans to a thickness of 1.5 inches, you would need 2.49 cups. To fill both pans to a depth of 2 inches, you would need 3.32 cups of batter.

That's a 6X2 inch rectangle, of indeterminate depth, which is how I interpreted your question. A round pan with a diameter of 6 inches would hold 28.3 cubic inches of batter for each inch of depth. 28.3 cubic inches equals 1.98 cups.

Here's a [conversion site](http://www.traditionaloven.com/culinary-arts/volume/convert-cubic-inch-in3-to-cup-us.html) for cubic inches to cups.

A 6"x2" rectangle is an odd shape and size, so I included an answer to another possible interpretation of your question. Please comment, especially if you don't feel that I've fully answered your question.

Comment: Your calculation here uses batter depth, but I assume that the OP wants to achieve a certain sheet thickness, and the starting depth of the batter isn't important. Indeed, depending on the batter, there is a lower boundary of sheet thickness (the cake always breaks if you try to make it thinner) and an upper boundary of sheet thickness (the cake doesn't bake in the center). Somebody who works with box mix frequently will know these boundaries, and know the rise factor, so could give an estimate of the usable range.

Comment: @rumtscho I'm kind of assuming that the OP knows the depth of batter she wants, that she has made the cake before. It is the depth of the batter is the primary variable to determine the thickness of the sheet. I understand the question to be asking how to convert this measurement that can be expressed in cubic inches, to cups.